# SQL Server 2012 extended event session to expose the network protocol

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, extended-events

I am using SQL Server 2012 (11.0.5058.0) [extended events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630282(v=sql.110).aspx), and wish to know the [network protocol](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187892(v=sql.105).aspx) used by each connection (TCP/IP, shared memory etc).

[Event session created](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677289.aspx) for the login event via: -

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Login] ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.login(
    ACTION(
sqlserver.client_app_name
,sqlserver.client_connection_id
,sqlserver.client_hostname
,sqlserver.client_pid
...
...
```

I have added all available actions for the login event (SELECT * FROM sys.dm_xe_objects WHERE package_guid = '655FD93F-3364-40D5-B2BA-330F7FFB6491' AND object_type = 'action' ORDER BY name) but none appear to give the network protocol.

It may be of course that Login is not the correct event to give this information, but I can't see a connection event (or similar) within the [XE DMV](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(DM_XE_OBJECTS_TSQL);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true).

To confirm, I want an extended event session to expose the net_transport information that is returned by [dm_exec_connections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(DM_EXEC_CONNECTIONS_TSQL);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true): -

```
SELECT net_transport FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.

The login event is correct and the network protocol is exposed via the options_text action. options_text was always blank for me previously and this needs to be set on via **SET collect_options_text=(1)**. An example session might be: -

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Login] ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.login(SET collect_options_text=(1)
    ACTION(
    sqlserver.session_id
    ,sqlserver.username
    ))
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer
WITH (
    MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,
    EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,
    MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=1 SECONDS,
    MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,
    MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,
    TRACK_CAUSALITY=ON,
    STARTUP_STATE=ON
)
GO
```

And this would then populate options_text with something like: -

> network protocol: TCP/IP  set quoted_identifier on  set arithabort off
>   set numeric_roundabort off  set ansi_warnings on  set ansi_padding on 
>   set ansi_nulls on  set concat_null_yields_null on  set
>   cursor_close_on_commit off  set implicit_transactions off  set
>   language us_english  set dateformat mdy  set datefirst 7  set
>   transaction isolation level read committed

I found this out be chance by creating a session from the "Connection Tracking" Microsoft shipped extended events template.

SSMS | Management | Extended Events | Sessions | Right click | New session | General page | Template = Connection Tracking.

That template includes "SET collect_options_text=(1)" and I wasn't previously aware such an option existed.

An example is also given in this [sql-server-performance article](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2013/extended-events-in-sql-server-2012/). The last screenshot shows options_text populated with "network protocol: LPC.." LPC is [shared memory](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187892(v=sql.105).aspx).